# What does "TypeError: props.data.map is not a function" mean and how to solve it in react

Tags: reactjs

This code is written for a component named LISTVIEW_COMPONENT.js. The parent component called INDEX.JS.
INDEX.JS has passed a prop into this component named data which is basically a test data dictionary.
 When I tried to loop through the props.data it gives me an error
 
**"TypeError: props.data.map is not a function"**

```
LISTVIEW_COMPONENT.JS

import React from "react";
import ListItemComponent from "./Listitem_component";

const ListViewComponent = props => {
    const DATA = props.data.map(list_item => {
        return (<ListItemComponent key={list_item.key} data={list_item} />);
    });
    return <ul>{DATA}</ul>;
};
export default ListViewComponent;





INDEX.JS

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SearchComponent from "./components/Search_component";
import ListViewComponent from "./components/Listview_component";

const API_KEY = "";
const DATA = ({
    key: 1,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary one"
},
{
    key: 2,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary two"
},
{
    key: 3,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary three"
});

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    do_search(keyword) {
        console.log(keyword);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchComponent
                    searchkeyword={keyword => {
                        this.do_search(keyword);
                    }}
                />
                <ListViewComponent data={DATA} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: "map" is a function of Array type. Convert your DATA to array type , then "map" will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap you objects in `data` in an array, otherwise `.map` will not work. Right now you're using `()` which will not work.

```
const DATA = ({
    key: 1,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary one"
},
{
    key: 2,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary two"
},
{
    key: 3,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary three"
});
```

Should be

```
const DATA = [{
    key: 1,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary one"
},
{
    key: 2,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary two"
},
{
    key: 3,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary three"
}]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for mentioning my mistake. It solved that error

Comment: Happy to help, accept my answer, to let others know your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is for array. This code is invalide:

```
const DATA = ({
    key: 1,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary one"
},
{
    key: 2,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary two"
},
{
    key: 3,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary three"
});
```

and result to a simple object.

If you add `console.log(DATA)`, you will see the following object:

```
{
    key: 3,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary three"
}
```

Refacto as follow to get a correct array:

```
const DATA = [{
    key: 1,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary one"
},
{
    key: 2,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary two"
},
{
    key: 3,
    src: "http://via.placeholder.com/64x64",
    summary: "this is summary three"
}];
```